# Read in mulitple Files and Array List

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

I want to save every line in my files into an Array List.
When i have only one file it works fine, but if i readin multiple files the first line of every file are all saved in the same Array... 
Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    File folder = new File("\\Documents\\Files");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for(File file : listOfFiles) {
       dosomething(file);
    }
}

public static void dosomething(File file)
{
    try {
        List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String[] tmp;
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            tmp = line.split("\n");
            if (tmp.length > 0) {
                lines.add(tmp);
            }

        }

        reader.close();
        System.out.println(lines.get(0)); 

    }
    ....
}
```

Result:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742
[Ljava.lang.String;@6d06d69c
[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922
```

In my folder "files" i have 3 file.txt and every file contains lines of text.
So i wanted  do save every line of every file into a new Array. But why i have no 3 Lines saved instead of 1 one?

Can someone helpme?

### Thanks

Now i tried it this way:

```
public static String [] stringArr;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        File folder = new File("\\Documents\\Files");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for(File file : listOfFiles) {
                dosomething(file);
        }
         List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

            for(String s : stringArr)
            {
                lines.add(s);
            }

            for(String t : lines)
            {
                System.out.println(t);
             }
    }
    public static void dosomething(File file)
    {
        try {
            List<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String str;
                    while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
                            list.add(str);
                    }
                    stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

                    }
                    reader.close();
            }
```

Result: If do a for-loop of stringArr in the dosomthing methode, every contant of each file perfectly saved in my stringArr.... but now if i do the for loop in the Main-methode i just get the content of one file back...

Comment: you need to print the arrays properly

Comment: Also look into `Files.readAllLines`

Comment: You may put the ArrayList in the main, because you're creating a new one each time you enter in the method, so for each file

Comment: You should not `line.split("\n")` , because `reader.readLine()` is already doing it for you

Comment: Each Iteration you are creating `arraylist` and `array` thats the reason you are getting three . What you need to do is create list and array in the main and read all the text set in to the array and add to the list .You can print `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lines.get(0)));`

Comment: @soorapadman  watch the Answer i posted

Comment: @tradeJmark i allready tried that

Comment: Why are you splitting the lines gotten from `reader.readLine` on `"\n"`? Those `String`s shouldn't be able to contain any newlines, should they? `readLine` should never read in a newline character.

Comment: @tradeJmark i already fixed that, but this wasnt the solution of my Problem so... =(

Comment: @k.bo what is your expected output look like again you are not going right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need a list of  arrays to store the lines but can be simply stored in a String.
so

```
List<String> lines=new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(tmp);
    }
```

will suffice the need of storing the lines from file into your arraylist.

For printing the lines from the list you can just iterate over your list and print them.

```
for(String string : lines ){
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

**EDIT** after OP edited the question

1.Why to again use `String[] stringArr` instead use it as a list and add lines to it. I see your whole intention is to store the lines of all three files in a list(or array) which is used to print them all at once

```
public  List<String> globalList;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   globalList=newArrayList<String>();
   File folder = new File("\\Documents\\Files");
   File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

   for(File file : listOfFiles) {
       dosomething(file);
   }

   for(String t : globalList) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
public static void dosomething(File file)
{
    try {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String str;
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            globalList.add(str);
         }
     }
     reader.close();
 }
```

Comment: Yes i've now change that, but the Problem is if im working with my Saved array `public static String [] stringArr;` in the Main methode i only have saved there one file content, if I do `for(String out : stringArr){System.out.println(out);` in my dosomthing method, then i have everything saved in this array...

Comment: but why do you want a stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

Comment: Because im stupid xD Thank you ver much sir! Now its working

Comment: Never stupid if you accept suggestions when they are right and follow them instead of always going on your approach

Comment: =) Thanks enjoy your day!